# I want to get list of top 250 movies of imdb but I'm unable as it give me "{}" not whole list

Tags: java, android

I have added libraries properly there is no one error but it is not showing desired result. I have got the return type string and saved it to a variable and then set it text view. I have stuck here. Please help me.

```
public String TableToJson() throws JSONException {
    int i=0;

    String s="http://www.imdb.com/chart/top";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
    JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject();
    //JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            i++;
            String no = Integer.toString(i);
            String Name = tds.get(1).text();
            String rating = tds.get(2).text();

            jsonObject.put("Ranking", no);
            jsonObject.put("Title", Name);
            jsonObject.put("Rating", rating);

            jsonParentObject.put(Name, jsonObject);
        }
    }
    return jsonParentObject.toString();
}
```

and output is only

```
{}
```

Comment: It's times like these when a debugger comes in handy

Comment: Don't you think you need to first parse `<tbody>` before `<tr>` ? @Princess's Prince

Comment: Tried it also but same problem...@AkshayMahajan

Comment: What JSON are you trying to parse exactly? That's just a HTML webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see just using a regular expression will work for you.

[image: IDMB top 250 web source]

Sample query can be similar to this

```
<strong title=".*</strong>
```

Showing 250 matches [Tested using freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)
[image: Showing 250 matches]